# Why does this greedy algorithm work?

Tags: greedy

Here's the problem:

> Given a sequence s of + and - characters which represent +1 and -1 operations respectively on a variable x with initial value 0, find the maximum range of values x can achieve with any subsequence of s.

Example:

> s = +--+--+, x = 0
>
> Subsequence that would lead to the maximum range of 4 is +----+. x would have max value 1 and min value -3.

The solution for this algorithm in pseudo-code is as follows:

```
count_minus = #occurrences of - character
count_plus = #occurences of + character
return max(count_minus, count_plus)
```

Why does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove all the positives then you have `max=0` and `min=-#negatives` for `range=#negatives`. Similarly for removing the negatives. Can't really get any better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I didn't understand though is, in the example that I gave the correct subsequence has both positives and negatives.

Comment: Yeah. It's *a* maximal subsequence, but not a *unique* maximal subsequence. `+----` is also a maximal sequence. (Also +1 and -3 for range=4). `----` is also a maximal subsequence (0 and -4 for range=4). Assume #neg>#pos. Removing all pos achieves `range = #neg` . Then argue, by induction on #pos<#neg that no other subsequence has greater range. Add a positive. You have to add it where the number of negatives before it <= the number of positives before it to affect the range. But then there are more negatives after it than positives, so in the end, it didn't help.